# Sequential Number not Sequence

Tags: sequential

i have problem with sequential ID in sharepoint, the picture below.

[image]

I did not remove ID 22 but the ID 22 is missing automatically.

can i get back the ID 22? because the sequential number not sequence.

sorry for my english.
Thank you

Comment: 003623 , 003621 is SharePoint default item ID ? if not, can you post view with item ID column into it.

Answer (score 0):

Seen it happen only once before,

The thing is, ID is not sequential, it is a unique number per list, created (never updated!) by SharePoint on Item creation.

If the underlying database at time N encounters a problem (maybe multiple requests/edits at the same time) it can happen that ID skips a number

*or so we concluded many moons ago*,

thus we decided you can not **rely** on ID being sequential